# Redis Ordered Set of objects with O(1) retrieval by a GUID key and sorted by another 64-bit signed integer key in descending order

Tags: redis, set, linkedhashmap, redis-cluster, ordered-set

I have a map of sets of unique objects, unique based on it's GUID as key, and sorted by timestamp, a 64-bit signed integer in descending order. The sets are keyed by a GUID and every individual object in the each set should be able to be retrieved by it's GUID in O(1). I need to store this map into Redis cache. I have read of Redis Ordered Set. However, my question is how to `ZADD` the object into the ordered set for later retrieval by the object's GUID as key in O(1) time and sorted by the 64-bit signed int timestamp in descending order? Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure I got you right, you want the set unique value is the GUID but you want to retrieve sorted by the timestamp? why do you need a set do you get the GUID updated more than once?

Comment: It's like `LinkedHashMap` in Java.

Comment: Keyed on GUID and ordered on timestamp.